# The asignCards() function is supposed to give random cards from the cards array to each player

Tags: json

This asignCards() function is supposed to give random cards from the cards array to each player. The cards are not supposed to be repeated but I get repeated cards.

// For each player in the array of players, each player receives two cards.

```
    const asignCards = () => {
      players.forEach((player) => {
        let useCards = [];
        let inUse = cards;

        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
          let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
          if (
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random])) === -1 ||
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random2])) === -1 ||
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random])) !==
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random2]))
          ) {
            player.card1 = inUse[random];
            player.card2 = inUse[random2];
           useCards.push(JSON.stringify(player.card1));
          useCards.push(JSON.stringify(player.card2));
          }else {
            i--;
          }
        }
        console.log(player);
      });
   };

   asignCards();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `useCards` array outside of the loop, otherwise everytime it will be empty at each iteration. Put it that way, you can not have duplicate for a player, but the same card can be assigned to more players.

```js
    const asignCards = () => {

      let useCards = [];

      players.forEach((player) => {
        let inUse = cards;
        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
          let random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
          if (
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random])) === -1 ||
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random2])) === -1 ||
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random])) !==
            useCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(inUse[random2]))
          ) {
            player.card1 = inUse[random];
            player.card2 = inUse[random2];
           useCards.push(JSON.stringify(player.card1));
          useCards.push(JSON.stringify(player.card2));
          }else {
            i--;
          }
        }
        console.log(player);
      });
   };

   asignCards();
```

**Bonus**: you may want to rename your function to assignCards (from [assign](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assign)) with double `s`.

---

Update:
Here's a different approach. Every time you want to play you shuffle the deck first, then pick your amount of cards from the top of the deck with [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), so you're 100% sure there will be no duplicates.

```js
let players = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
let cards = [...Array(52).keys()];
const cardsPerPlayer = 2;

const asignCards = () => {

  // Shuffle deck
  var n = cards.length;
  while (n--) {
    var i = Math.floor(n * Math.random());
    var tmp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[n];
    cards[n] = tmp;

  }

  players.forEach((player, index) => {
    let myCards = [];
    for (c = 0; c < cardsPerPlayer; c++) {
      myCards.push(cards.pop());
    }

    console.log(`${player} has the following cards: ${myCards}`);
  });
};

asignCards();
```

Comment: But they are not suppose to be repeated even among players.

Comment: I updated the answer with a different approach, feel free to have a look :)